# kubernetes change PVC from ReadWriteOnce to ReadWriteMany

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to change an existing PVC to ReadWriteMany from ReadWriteOnce without recreating it?  I have an existing database pod and the file system has become read only for some reason.  I wanted to connect another pod to the PVC to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so without changing the PVC. The *Once* in `ReadWriteOnce` is not about the number of Pods accessing the PVC but about the number of Nodes accessing it.

Create another Pod mounting the same PVC and set `nodeSelector` (use [hostname](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#interlude-built-in-node-labels)) so it schedules on the same node where the PVC is mounted now.

Alternatively SSH into the node that has the PVC mounted already for the Pod. `kubectl describe ...` gives you the id you are looking for if you have many mounts.

Comment: so `nodeSelector` is the way to ensure pods run into the same node? currently, I'm using GKE and I have a PVC. I have Postgres and application deployments and both of them mount the volume. sometimes it will get stuck when I deploy config files, I guess it because standard storage is only `ReadWriteOnce` supported and in case the pods of two deployments on different nodes will result in stuck issue. any suggestion? thanks, Jason

Comment: Can you make them use different volumes?

Comment: I didn't know what is the best practice. I would like to share all persisted data in one volume. like DB data, user's uploads... and mount them by different `subPath`. I thought it will be convenient. because all of them are in one place. sure, I can make them different volumes.

Comment: the last question. if I make them use different volumes, the issue will be solved. so did you mean for the one deployment object. if a new verison(new image) is applied, we can ensure new pod and old pod will be in the same node? but for different deployments, we can't ensure pods are in the same node, right? sorry for too many question.

Comment: I just do a quick experiment to set deployment replicas to 10. the 10 pods are in different nodes. so, even I make them use different volumes, the issue can't be solved. for example, I have a volume with ReadWriteOnce for user's uploading purpose. I mount the volume in pod of deployment, and set `replicas` to 10. 10 pods are possible to be in different node. this update will get stuck. because of `ReadWriteOnce`.

Comment: How does this answer the question "Is it possible to change an existing PVC to ReadWriteMany from ReadWriteOnce without recreating it?" ? 

And yes I do understand what you're explaining, it just doesn't answer the question from OP

Comment: While this appears to have helped the OP, it does not answer the question. Is there a way to update the question so that people who actually *need* to change to ReadWriteMany (in my case for scaling the deployment across multiple nodes) are not directed here?

Answer (score 7):

Whilst **it is not possible** to change persistent volume claim from ReadWriteOnce to ReadWriteMany **without destroying the persistent volume claim** (they are immutable), there is a procedure.

I am writing this here, since same as others I landed here and the question is written without mentioning avoidance of recreation of the PVC.

Here is the docs in kubernetes itself: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/09/13/read-write-once-pod-access-mode-alpha/

The example in the docs is to change access mode to `ReadWriteOncePod` but the principle is identical.

Below is an example and details that I stumbled upon when doing this myself converting access mode from `ReadWriteOnce` to `ReadWriteMany`.

I am converting a PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim for my grafana helm release which is in grafana namespace.

PeristentVolume name: `grafana-pv`

PersistentVolumeClaim name: `grafana-pvc`

Namespace: `grafana`

Adjust commands accordingly to your use case please.

## Backup of existing resources

Just in case anything super bad happens, do at least a backup of existing persistent volume claim. We will need to delete it and that's best practice.

Even if you have the code that generated the original PVC, do a backup.

In case you fail to find actual manifest that generated it, you can recreate it then easily from the backup (once you change the access mode).

```bash
kubectl get pvc grafana-pvc -n grafana -o yaml > grafana_pvc_backup.yaml
```

## Change reclaim policy of the persistent volume to `Retain`

**This is required**!!! Before you delete the persistent volume claim to avoid a surprise that your data got wiped. The default reclaim policy is `Delete` and we do not want that to happen.

```bash
kubectl patch pv grafana-pv -n grafana -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'
```

## Scale down any workloads (deployments, stateful sets etc etc) using the volume

In this step you are removing binds to the persistent volume. Check what is using it and scale it down to 0. No need to delete deployments, just scale them down to no pods running.

```bash
kubectl scale --replicas=0 -n grafana deployment grafana
```

When all workloads using the persistent volume have been scaled down to zero you should see the status of it change from `Bound` to `Released`. We are not done yet though.

## Delete existing persistent volume claim to be able to free persistent volume

NOTE: **Did you back up its manifest just in case?**

```bash
kubectl delete pvc grafana-pvc -n grafana
```

## Free persistent volume status to become `Available`

Here we just remove the reference to the deleted persistent volume claim from the persistent volume so that a new persistent volume claim can be set.

```bash
kubectl patch pv grafana-pv -n grafana -p '{"spec":{"claimRef":{"uid":""}}}'
```

You should see that status of the persistent volume changed to `Available`

## Change the persistent volume access mode to ReadWriteMany

Just run this command:

```bash
kubectl patch pv grafana-pv -n grafana -p '{"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteMany"]}}'
```

## Recreate persistent volume claim with access mode ReadWriteMany

Here you either use your existing code to create this kubernetes resource with access mode `ReadWriteMany` or just use the backup we did in first step, edit its spec.accessModes and apply that.

I am just showing what the part of `spec` that is interesting to us should be, if you are editing existing manifest or backup, you will easily find the place to change it.

```yaml
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
```

Apply the new persistent volume claim manifest (assuming we saved it to a file called `persistent_volume_claim_read_write_many.yaml`:

```bash
kubectl -n grafana apply -f persistent_volume_claim_read_write_many.yaml
```

## Scale the workloads back up to start using the volume with new access mode.

Adjust number of replicas to what your workloads manifests actually specify.

```bash
kubectl scale --replicas=1 -n grafana deployment grafana
```

The status of you persistent volume should become `Bound` now.

## Important checks

Now all the workloads should start using your persistent volume in `ReadWriteMany` access mode.

Check all containers and make sure they actually were able to attach the volume correctly.

## Restore reclaim policy of your persistent volume

If you want it to go back to what it was (assumed `Delete`) and its status is `Bound` (meaning something is using it, and **it will not get wiped** if reclaim policy is changed to `Delete`).

```bash
kubectl patch pv grafana-pv -n grafana -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Delete"}}'
```

That's it. All done. I have carried this out and it works. If there are any mistakes - let me know, I will amend the answer.

Comment: Excellent instructions! My only comment would be in response to this -

_"When all workloads using the persistent volume have been scaled down to zero you should see the status of it change from Bound to Released."_

The status of the PV that I was attempting to modify only changed from 'Bound' to 'Released'  **after** I deleted the relevant PVC. (that is, even when the deployment was scaled to zero, the PV was still showing 'Bound', until the PVC was removed)

Comment: Very well described.

Comment: Applying the original file before the backup worked for me, otherwise I could not get the state to go from Available to Bound