# edit pvc from ReadWriteOnce to ReadWriteMany

Tags: kubernetes

We have pvc with access policy

```
     accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
```

we want to change it to **ReadWriteMany** does it possible to edit pvc without deleting it?

I know I can create it with deleting it but I dont want to delete it.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321024/kubernetes-change-pvc-from-readwriteonce-to-readwritemany) but it didn't helped me. This is oppsite of my use case.

Answer (score -1):

I tried editing it using `kubectl edit pvc <pvc_name>` and this is the output of the error when submititng changes:

```
persistentvolumeclaims "task-pv-claim" was not valid:
spec: Forbidden: is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
```

This means you cannot edit claim after it has been created, either using `kubectl edit` nor `kubectl patch`.